# Get average delay time

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, summarize

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
fli = flights
fli %>% 
   filter(origin=="JFK" & dest=="SEA") %>% 
   summarise(meandelay= mean(dep_delay))
```

i was expecting a column of average time but I got NA

Comment: We need to reassign it to fli to see the changes: `fli <- fli %>% ...`

Comment: @zx8754   yeah I tried, but it didn't work. Maybe there's something wrong in my RStudio or the data, or I'm missing something

Comment: Data has NAs, remove before getting the mean: `mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @zx8754 oh wow, I'm such an noob. Thanks for the help man!